# Historical Question, Possible Wade-Giles, Sichuan river name

Tags: history, romanization

I am currently reading an entomologists diaries from the late 19th Century - A.E. Pratt. He travelled Sichuan Province and published his journal, *[To the Snows of Tibet through China](https://archive.org/details/tosnowsoftibetth00pratrich)*, in 1892. Pratt keeps referring to the *Tung* River; however, I can find no corresponding river, today.

There are a couple of problems, the first being that names change frequently throughout the frontier's particularly turbulent pre-modern history.

Pratt mentions *Fu-lin* (which I am assuming is modern day *[Fuling](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fuling,+Chongqing,+China/@29.5854082,106.8238431,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x369300832bb0e82b:0xaafda18e375b4c45!8m2!3d29.703113!4d107.389298)* which he also mentions). Pratt mentions the Yangtse by name, so the Tung is not the Yangtse on which Fuling sits.

So, here is my question: assuming Pratt was using somthing akin to Wade-Gile's system of romanization, what would the *pinyin* equivalent be, i.e. I can't remember what "T" is in Wade-Giles? Is anyone aware of the *Tung*?

Comment: Probably "dong" as in east?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tung river is the translation of 銅河, it's called 大渡河 (Dadu river) now.

On page 127 of the "to the snows of tibet through china", it was written:

> . . . Lu-ting-chiao, which is built on both banks of the Tung River, . . .

Well, Lu-ting-chiao is 瀘定橋.

BTW, there's a map on page 353, you may compare it with other source :)

Another interesting book about tibet, thanks :)